# Cleanly placing a checkbox within a thumbnail image

Tags: html, css

In the code sample below I would like the each thumbnail-image to be overlayed with a checkbox. There should be no white space up top. The "left" and "right" divs should be vertically aligned at their Tops.

I would like the images to fill all of the table cell space.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>
#container {
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-size: 0px;
}
#left {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    display: inline;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing: 0; 
    margin: 0 ;
    }
td { padding: 0px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table >
<tr>
<td>
<div id="container" data-role="main">
<div id="left" >
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1l0Rwz8GHUGY58lLems8FNyn9UrTFHX4HaA" height="185" width="100%">
</div>
<div id="right">  
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="container" data-role="main"><!--class="ui-content"-->
<div id="left">
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1l0Rwz8GHUGY58lLems8FNyn9UrTFHX4HaA" height="185" width="100%">
</div>
<div id="right">  
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car" checked>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Each table cell should look like a box at the bottom of this screen: 
[image: Screen to look like this:]

Comment: your img google drive source is not correct. can you add in the sample image to check and also can you put in a screenshot of the desired output you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I have modified the question to make more clear and added a sample image also. The source image is not important they are just there for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID; you need to use classes instead for left, right, and container.

Instead of `display: inline` for your elements, if you want one on top of the other, you need to use `position: relative` for the container and `position: absolute` for the overlaying element.

```
.container {
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-size: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.left {

}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4yvptr9/3/

If you wanted to get rid of the table, you could use `display: inline-block` on the `.container` elements.  You would need to comment out the line-break between the `</div>` and `<div>` to get rid of the white line between the two pictures - with `display: inline-block`, the browser leaves space for the white-space in the HTML, so you have to trick it by either not putting the next tag on a new line or by "hiding" the breaks.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4yvptr9/5/